# The - (dash) disappears in document url

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, footnotes, punctuation

I have the following problem. I am writing a paper in LaTeX and at some point I am adding a URL as a footnote.

It looks like this:

```
\footnote{\url{https://lists.inf.ethz.ch/pipermail/barrelfish-users/2011-July/000204.html}}
```

It renders the URL as expected. But when I click on the URL in the PDF-file, my browser opens the URL up to the first -, i.e. it opens

```
 https://lists.inf.ethz.ch/pipermail/barrelfish-
```

Anyone an idea why this does happen and how I can fix the problem?

---

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\title{random title}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}

MWE\footnote{\url{https://lists.inf.ethz.ch/pipermail/barrelfish-users/2011-July/000204.html}}
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The MWE following works as expected:


    `\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \begin{document}
    \footnote{\url{https://lists.inf.ethz.ch/pipermail    /barrelfish-users/2011-July/000204.html}}
    {\url{https://lists.inf.ethz.ch/pipermail/barrelfish-users/2011-July/000204.html}}
    \end{document}`


The problem seems to be somewhere else, so please try to prepare a [minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It might also help to know which pdf viewer you are using.

Comment: Here is a MWE were it does not work: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\title{random title}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}

MWE\footnote{\url{https://lists.inf.ethz.ch/pipermail/barrelfish-users/2011-July/000204.html}}
\end{abstract}

\end{document}

Comment: Okay, I found a workaround. Apparently, it is not enough to add the package 
    
    url
but one has to additionally add
    
    hyperref

in order to have the expected behaviour when clicking on the link in the document. This is very strange, and I would actually still like to know why this behaviour occurs. This is VERY strange to me, but maybe someone here has a good explanation.

Comment: `url` alone does not add clickable links, this is done by hyperref, as already seen in my comment above.

hyperref should be loaded last (in most cases). Please be aware of that.

Comment: @AlbertHeinle Some PDF viewers have some builtin heuristics for recognizing URLs; they can be fooled quite easily by strange URLs. With `hyperref` you plant a real URL link in the PDF file.

Answer (score 5):

This is a 'feature' of the PDF viewer you are using. Some (most?) PDF viewers will attempt to find/'activate' links in plain text based on pattern matching. However, at the PDF itself does not contain a full hyperlink this may or may not be accurate. Adding the `hyperref` package normally fixes this as it includes a (PDF-level) hyperlink in the PDF when you use `\url`: just using the `url` package only makes the link human-readable.